# Actionscript reference question

Tags: actionscript-3, reference

I recently have done some refactoring to my project and I receive the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1065: root::transform is undefined
    at Root/__setPerspectiveProjection_()[Root::Root:4]
```

while constructing my main class `Root`.

*The only thing I've been doing was moving items froms different packages and I have no idea why this is happening. Could someone help?*

Thank you.

Comment: Is `Root::transform` defined anywhere?

Comment: @Anon As long as `Root` extends a `MovieClip`, it should be. Basically, everything was working until I did that package moving and now I'm trying to understand what actually happened)

Comment: So does `Root` actually extend `MovieClip` still?

Comment: @Anon Yes, it does in the actionscript code. I'm not that sure about the integration of Flash Builder and Flash CS5, but in the last one main document reference was changed appropriately. *Everything except the main movieclip transform works fine and I have no clue why does this happen.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had my package named `root` also and that made actionscript panick on `root.transform` calls.

**Renaming the package solved the problem.**

Comment: You should accept your own answer and close this question, then.